# Hover effect not working properly on each element after first time hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a code and here it is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#pop li').hover(
    function() {
        $('#s').removeClass('follower2').addClass('follower1');
        $('p.follower1').eq($(this).index()).show();
//                $("#s").css('display','none');
    }, function() {
        $('#s').removeClass('follower1').addClass('follower2');
        $('p.follower1').eq($(this).index()).hide();
    }); 

});
```

**About the code:**

The code is actually showing the elements on hover.

**What's the problem:**

The Problem by default there is Followers written on the page. On hover first time on Facebook, Twitter it disappear working and likes, tweets appers respectively ( fine till here as expected ) but when I hover on Instagram for the first the works as expected after hovering instagram the thing start going worng. On second hover the default Followers does not disapper.

Please check my [codepen](https://codepen.io/owaiz/pen/weqRPY) to see the problem

**UPDATED:**

**What I want:**

After hovering on the instagram the things going wrong I want to fix that ( means as I hover on the instagram and again I try to hover on facebook or twitter the follower for instagram does not disapper. How can I fix this

Comment: what do you excepted output ?

Comment: @Sumitpatel As you have see in my codepen. After hovering on the instagram the things going wrong I want to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pop ul li').hover(function(){
        $('.col-md-3 p').css('display','none');
        $('.col-md-3 p').eq($(this).index()).css('display','block');
    })
})
```

```css
.follower1 {
    display: none;
}
.follower2 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pop">
  <ul class="list-inline social-icon">
      <li><a href="#!"><span>FaceBook</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#!"><span>Twitter</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#!"><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 align-center">
    <p class="follower1">Likes<br>1,082</p>
    <p class="follower1">Twitter<br>3,023</p>
    <p id="s" class="follower2">Followers<br>2,089</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you have handled the classes is the problem, you can simplify it to

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pop li').hover(function() {
    $('#s p').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
  }, function() {
    $('#s p').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#s .follower{display: none;}
#s .follower:last-child{display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pop">
  <ul class="list-inline social-icon">
    <li><a href="#!"><span>FaceBook</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><span>Twitter</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="s" class="col-md-3 align-center">
  <p class="follower">Likes<br>1,082</p>
  <p class="follower">Twitter<br>3,023</p>
  <p class="follower">Followers<br>2,089</p>
</div>
```